# Changing Subgrid filter throwing error in dynamics crm 2015

Tags: crm, dynamics-crm-2015, fetchxml

Good afternoon. I am running into a REALLY wierd issue trying to change a datagrid, and google hasn't been any luck. I am using the below javascripts to set the fetch and layout of a subgrid called "Opp_Prods".

```
function timeOutReassignFilter()
{
console.log("About to setTimeout");
    setTimeout(SetProductView, 1000);
console.log("Set TimeOut");
}

function SetProductView()
{
try
{
var accountId = Xrm.Page.data.entity.getId();
var viewId = '{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001}';
var entityName = "opportunityproduct";
var viewDisplayName = "Associated Opportunity Products View";

console.log("About to set fetchxml: " + accountId);
var fetchXml = "<fetch version='1.0' output-format='xml-platform' mapping='logical' distinct='false'>" + 
  "<entity name='opportunityproduct'>" +
    "<attribute name='productid' />" +
    "<attribute name='productdescription' />" +
    "<attribute name='priceperunit' />" +
    "<attribute name='quantity' />" +
    "<attribute name='new_serialnumber' />" +
    "<attribute name='extendedamount' />" +
    "<attribute name='opportunityproductid' />" +
    "<order attribute='productid' descending='false' />" +
    "<link-entity name='opportunity' from='opportunityid' to='opportunityid' alias='ac'>" +
      "<filter type='and'>" +
        "<condition attribute='parentaccountid' operator='eq' value='" + accountId + "' />" + //uiname='Test Account' 
      "</filter>" +
    "</link-entity>" +
  "</entity>" +
"</fetch>";

console.log("About to set layoutXml");
var layoutXml = "<grid name='Opp_Prods' object='1' jump='productid' select='1' icon='1' preview='1'>" +
    "<row name='result' id='myproductid'>" +
        "<cell name='productdescription' width='150' />" +
        "<cell name='productid' width='150' />" +
        "<cell name='priceperunit' width='150' />" +
        "<cell name='quantity' width='150' />" +
        "<cell name='extendedamount' width='150' />" +
        "<cell name='new_serialnumber' width='150' />" +
        "<cell name='opportunityproductid' width='150' />" +
    "</row>" +
"</grid>";

console.log("About to set Control by adding custom view.");
//    Xrm.Page.getControl("opp_prods").addCustomView(viewId, entityName, viewDisplayName, fetchXml, layoutXml, true);

document.getElementById("Opp_Prods").control.SetParameter("fetchXML", fetchXml);
document.getElementById("Opp_Prods").control.SetParameter("layoutXML", layoutXml);
Xrm.Page.ui.controls.get("Opp_Prods").refresh();
console.log("Custom View Added.");
}
catch(err)
{
console.log(err);
}
}
```

When the form loads, it's throwing the following error:

> Unhandled Exception:
>   System.ServiceModel.FaultException`1[[Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OrganizationServiceFault,
>   Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk, Version=7.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]: System.Xml.XmlException: Microsoft
>   Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for
>   administrators or support: #E63BFD86Detail:  
>   -2147220970      System.Xml.XmlException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has
>   experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support:
>
> ## E63BFD86   2015-08-25T16:13:21.2028543Z
>
> ```
> <ErrorCode>-2147220970</ErrorCode>
> <ErrorDetails xmlns:d3p1="http://schemas.datacontract.org/2004/07/System.Collections.Generic"
> ```
>
> />
>       System.InvalidCastException: Microsoft Dynamics CRM has experienced an error. Reference number for administrators or support:
>
> ## F2D68509
>
> ```
> <Timestamp>2015-08-25T16:13:21.2028543Z</Timestamp>
> <InnerFault i:nil="true" />
> <TraceText i:nil="true" />   </InnerFault>   <TraceText i:nil="true" /> </OrganizationServiceFault>
> ```

And here's the full trace from our CRM trace logs:

> [2015-08-25 11:24:37.314] Process: w3wp
>   |Organization:f6d279c3-1548-e511-80bd-00155d001302 |Thread:  118
>   |Category: Application |User: 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000
>   |Level: Error |ReqId: 021d486e-5560-4f4e-a87a-a138ee9f8f3f |
>   ErrorInformation.LogError  ilOffset = 0x17
>
> > MSCRM Error Report:
> >     -------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------- Error: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
> >     'System.DBNull' to type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue'.    at
> >     Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.Grid.UI.PropertyTemplatePropertiesConfigurationColumn.BindData(WebControl
> >     parentControl, IRowDataSource rowData)    at
> >     System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)    at
> >     System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()    at
> >     System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)    at
> >     System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32
> >     dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, DataControlRowState
> >     rowState, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem, DataControlField[]
> >     fields, TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource)
> >     at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable
> >     dataSource, Boolean dataBinding)    at
> >     System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable
> >     data)    at
> >     System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable
> >     data)    at
> >     System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable
> >     data)    at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect()
> >     at
> >     Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.Grid.UI.LayoutProviderGridList.RenderGridData(HtmlTextWriter
> >     output)    at
> >     Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.Grid.UI.LayoutProvider.Render(HtmlTextWriter
> >     output)    at
> >     Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.GridUIProvider.Render(HtmlTextWriter
> >     output)    at
> >     Microsoft.Crm.Core.Application.WebServices.AppGridWebServiceHandler.GetRefreshResponseHtml(IGridUIProvider
> >     uiProvider, StringBuilder sbTemp)    at
> >     Microsoft.Crm.Core.Application.WebServices.AppGridWebServiceHandler.Refresh(String
> >     gridXml, StringBuilder sbXml, StringBuilder sbHtml, Boolean
> >     returnJsonData)    at
> >     Microsoft.Crm.Core.Application.WebServices.AppGridWebServiceHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext
> >     context)
>
> Error Message: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of
>   type 'System.DBNull' to type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue'.    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.Grid.UI.PropertyTemplatePropertiesConfigurationColumn.BindData(WebControl
>   parentControl, IRowDataSource rowData)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32
>   dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, DataControlRowState
>   rowState, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem, DataControlField[]
>   fields, TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource)
>   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable
>   dataSource, Boolean dataBinding)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable
>   data)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable
>   data)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable
>   data)    at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.Grid.UI.LayoutProviderGridList.RenderGridData(HtmlTextWriter
>   output)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.Grid.UI.LayoutProvider.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   output)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.GridUIProvider.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   output)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Core.Application.WebServices.AppGridWebServiceHandler.GetRefreshResponseHtml(IGridUIProvider
>   uiProvider, StringBuilder sbTemp)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Core.Application.WebServices.AppGridWebServiceHandler.Refresh(String
>   gridXml, StringBuilder sbXml, StringBuilder sbHtml, Boolean
>   returnJsonData)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Core.Application.WebServices.AppGridWebServiceHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext
>   context)
>
> Source File: Not available
>
> Line Number: Not available
>
> Request URL:
>   https://manufacturingdemo.crm2015.cloudappsonline.net/AppWebServices/AppGridWebService.ashx?operation=Refresh
>
> Stack Trace Info: [InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of type
>   'System.DBNull' to type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue'.]    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.Grid.UI.PropertyTemplatePropertiesConfigurationColumn.BindData(WebControl
>   parentControl, IRowDataSource rowData)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32
>   dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, DataControlRowState
>   rowState, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem, DataControlField[]
>   fields, TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource)
>   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable
>   dataSource, Boolean dataBinding)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable
>   data)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable
>   data)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable
>   data)    at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.Grid.UI.LayoutProviderGridList.RenderGridData(HtmlTextWriter
>   output)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.Grid.UI.LayoutProvider.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   output)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.GridUIProvider.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   output)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Core.Application.WebServices.AppGridWebServiceHandler.GetRefreshResponseHtml(IGridUIProvider
>   uiProvider, StringBuilder sbTemp)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Core.Application.WebServices.AppGridWebServiceHandler.Refresh(String
>   gridXml, StringBuilder sbXml, StringBuilder sbHtml, Boolean
>   returnJsonData)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Core.Application.WebServices.AppGridWebServiceHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext
>   context)
>
> [XmlException: System.InvalidCastException: Unable to cast object of
>   type 'System.DBNull' to type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue'.    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.Grid.UI.PropertyTemplatePropertiesConfigurationColumn.BindData(WebControl
>   parentControl, IRowDataSource rowData)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBindChildren()    at
>   System.Web.UI.Control.DataBind(Boolean raiseOnDataBinding)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateRow(Int32 rowIndex, Int32
>   dataSourceIndex, DataControlRowType rowType, DataControlRowState
>   rowState, Boolean dataBind, Object dataItem, DataControlField[]
>   fields, TableRowCollection rows, PagedDataSource pagedDataSource)
>   at System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.CreateChildControls(IEnumerable
>   dataSource, Boolean dataBinding)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.CompositeDataBoundControl.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable
>   data)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView.PerformDataBinding(IEnumerable
>   data)    at
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.OnDataSourceViewSelectCallback(IEnumerable
>   data)    at System.Web.UI.WebControls.DataBoundControl.PerformSelect()
>   at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.Grid.UI.LayoutProviderGridList.RenderGridData(HtmlTextWriter
>   output)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.Grid.UI.LayoutProvider.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   output)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Application.Controls.GridUIProvider.Render(HtmlTextWriter
>   output)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Core.Application.WebServices.AppGridWebServiceHandler.GetRefreshResponseHtml(IGridUIProvider
>   uiProvider, StringBuilder sbTemp)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Core.Application.WebServices.AppGridWebServiceHandler.Refresh(String
>   gridXml, StringBuilder sbXml, StringBuilder sbHtml, Boolean
>   returnJsonData)    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Core.Application.WebServices.AppGridWebServiceHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext
>   context)]    at
>   Microsoft.Crm.Core.Application.WebServices.AppGridWebServiceHandler.ProcessRequestInternal(HttpContext
>   context)    at
>   System.Web.HttpApplication.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
>   at System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step,
>   Boolean& completedSynchronously)

I am completely baffled, and help you guys can offer would be tremendously appreciated. The most troubling thing about this is that none of the fields I'm fetching are an option set, so what's going on here? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

So I think your approach is a bit off.

You are using unsupported JavaScript for starters `document.getElementById` which you should never expect to work.

The error `Unable to cast object of type 'System.DBNull' to type 'Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.OptionSetValue'` is a bit of an odd one. Looks like you can have set a `DBNull` value somehow which CRM isn't expecting.

There are supported methods for playing with the sub grid which will allow you to change the view, however they look quite different to your approach. See [Write scripts for subgrids](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn932137.aspx). For example:

```
var ContactsIFollow = {
 entityType: 1039, // SavedQuery
 id:"{3A282DA1-5D90-E011-95AE-00155D9CFA02}", 
 name: "Contacts I Follow"
}

Xrm.Page.getControl("Contacts").getViewSelector().setCurrentView(ContactsIFollow);
```

For sub grids it looks like you are only able to set an already existing view by Id, as opposed to your approach of changing the Layout and Fetch XML.

As a side, the lookup control does support setting the Layout and Fetch XML using [addCustomView](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg334266#BKMK_addCustomView). However the two controls - sub grid, & lookup are quite different and should not be confused.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, James. As far as I'm aware, there is no longer a "supported" way of appending custom fetch to a subgrid. The DBNull thing makes 0 sense to me because as I said, none of the fields I was fetching was an option set. The view I'm going to need will have to allow for dynamically replacing an account id, which is something "normal" views cannot do so using a pre-created view won't help. Also, the link you provided says it's only for online deployments, and we use on-premise. Thanks.